# What are functions outside of a class called?

Tags: python

I failed to phrase the question correctly online so I could not get an answer.

We have instance methods, static methods, and class methods.

What are functions called when they don't belong to a class?

Comment: They're just called functions.

Comment: some people call them free functions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're just called functions.

In python, "function" refers to a type of callable procedure/block of code with its own localized namespace.

In contrast, "method" refers specifically to a kind of function that is bound to a class. We use "instance methods", "static methods", and "class methods" to differentiate between *how* those functions are bound to their respective classes, but in any case we call them methods because they *are* bound to their class.

So, we just call them functions, unless we have something more specific. If you must use some sort of qualifier, "unbound function" (alluding to the fact that it's not bound to any class) or "module function" (alluding to the fact that it's bound to the module it's defined in, though that's not a class), or even "static function" (but this could be confusing when trying to communicate to people who don't know the difference between functions and methods) or "free function" will probably work.

Comment: Also worth noting that class methods and static methods are distinct types, created *from* functions. (They basically wrap functions in order to "override" their `__get__` methods to return something other than an instance method.)

Answer (score 3):

According to the section "Callable types" in the Python docs on its [Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

> A user-defined function object is created by a function definition

So I guess one could say that everything that begins with `def` is a function.

In general, I think it depends a lot on the context, which term you want to use. For example, even though, to define a "static method", you'd write `@staticmethod` and everything, it's not called a "method" but a "function" in the context of the `types` module:

```
>>> class A:
...     def f(self):
...         print("Hello from method `f`")
...     @staticmethod
...     def g():
...         print("Hello from function `g`")
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.f()
Hello from method `f`
>>> a.g()
Hello from function `g`
>>> type(a.f)
<class 'method'>
>>> type(a.g)
<class 'function'>
```

Furthermore, looking at the docs of Python's [`types`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html) module reveals:

> `types.MethodType` - The type of methods of user-defined class instances.

So methods are only found in **instances**. A method `b.f` of an instance `b` of a class `B` refers to the function `B.f` of the class:

```
>>> class B:
...     def f(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> b1 = B()
>>> type(b1.f)
<class 'method'>
>>> type(B.f)
<class 'function'>
```

The methods are different objects for each instance:

```
>>> b2 = B()
>>> b1.f is b2.f
False
```

However, the methods refer to the same function `B.f`:

```
>>> b1.f.__func__
<function B.f at 0x7f166e31b2f0>
>>> b1.f.__func__ is b2.f.__func__
True
```

I imagine, this can be both useful or a pitfall, so it makes sense to know about it.

Here is an example, using a class `C` with function `C.f` and `cache`, an [argument with a mutable default value](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments):

```
>>> class C:
...     def f(self, cache=[]):
...         cache.append(cache[-1] + 1 if cache else 1)
...         print(cache)
... 
>>> c1 = C()
>>> c2 = C()
>>> c1.f()
[1]
>>> c2.f()
[1, 2]
>>> c3 = C()
>>> c3.f()
[1, 2, 3]
```

As you can see, all instances `c1`, `c2` and `c3` of class `C` share the same underlying function `C.f` with its argument `cache`.

Comment: `LambdaType` is particularly pointless, as it is literally just a synonym for `FunctionType`; it's not a distinct type. The OP already knows that methods and functions are distinct.

Comment: Actually, they *are* functions. Methods come from accessing the functions as attributes via an instance.

Comment: @finefoot well, actually, at least according to `types`, it isn't a `MethodType` **until** it is called on the instance, i.e. let's say we have a class `Foo` with a method, `bar`, and an instance `foo = Foo()`, so `Foo.bar` is a function, and `foo.bar` is a method

Comment: @finefoot note furthermore, *each invocation of the method on an instance produces a different method object*. So `b1.f is b1.f` will give you `False`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, again, for your comment! :) This is fascinating insight. Where do you learn about this stuff?